# Disable auto update in spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA `@Entity` class. I retrieve the entity using one of the jpa's `findBy` methods which would be considered by `JPA` to be in the `persistent state`, then I update some of the fields in the entity, then pass the entity to validation. If the validation fails, then don't update, if validation succeeds then persist the entity.

Here is the main issue with this flow: because I updated the entity for it to be used in the validation, it does not matter whether I call `save()`, the record will always be updated because JPA detects that the entity has been changed and flags it for an update.

How to avoid this behavior?

My Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "user" )
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode( of = { "id" } )
@ToString( of = { "id" } )
public class UserModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "u_id" )
private Long id;

@Column( name = "u_first_name" )
private String firstName;

@Column( name = "u_last_name" )
private String lastName;

@Column( name = "u_email_id" )
private String emailId;

@Column( name = "u_password" )
private String password;

@Column( name = "u_mobile_number" )
private String mobileNumber;

@Column( name = "u_created_at" )
private Calendar createdAt;

@Column( name = "u_is_active" )
private Boolean isActive;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code (especially JPA entities involved + transaction demarcation related classes), nobody can help you.

Comment: Couldn't you use bean validation annotations on the entities? http://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: you could reload entity by its id...

Comment: You need to detach the entity yourself or make sure it gets detached. It's really your fault, you shouldn't be modifying an entity with potentially invalid values in the first place.

Comment: @Kayaman I have to update the user details. If the `emailId` is changed, then I should save the new details in a separate table, if not I need to persist. For that, I have to fetch the entity class and then update it. Otherwise, I will end up with duplicate code

Comment: Then you need to detach the entity like I said.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. When the validation fails detach the entity from the `EntityManager`.

   Make sure that you use appropriate cascade annotations or manually iterate through all entities that need detaching.
2. Do the whole update and validation in detached mode, i.e. in a method without `@Transactional` annotation. This way only when you explicitly call save the information will get stored.

   This might be a little simple to get right but has the drawback of loading all the affected entities twice.