# What are the steps required to create spring boot project using database first approach? Database used here is MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jboss

I am learning spring boot (for REST API). I have read spring boot documentation and other tutorials but all are based on creating database tables using entities (code first approach). One of the tutorials talked about JBoss(installed in from Eclipse marketplace). So I followed the tutorial and I was able to create entities, dao, pojo classes from database tables. But the tutorial doesn't talk about how to perform crud operations now. So I tried to perform some crud operation and I am getting errors.

**UserController**

```
package com.example.dbfirst.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.dbfirst.entities.User;
import com.example.dbfirst.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @RequestMapping("users/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        
        return this.userService.getUser(id);
        
    }
}
```

**UserService**

```
package com.example.dbfirst.service;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.dbfirst.dao.UserHome;
import com.example.dbfirst.entities.User;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    //@Autowired
    private UserHome userHome;
    public User getUser(int id) {
        userHome=new UserHome();
        return this.userHome.findById(id);
    }
}
```

**User DAO class using JBoss and hibernate.cfg.xml**
**UserHome**

```
package com.example.dbfirst.dao;
// Generated 25-Mar-2021, 4:50:30 pm by Hibernate Tools 5.2.12.Final

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.dbfirst.entities.User;

@Stateless
public class UserHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserHome.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void persist(User transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting User instance");
        try {
            entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public void remove(User persistentInstance) {
        log.debug("removing User instance");
        try {
            entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
            log.debug("remove successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("remove failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public User merge(User detachedInstance) {
        log.debug("merging User instance");
        try {
            User result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
            log.debug("merge successful");
            return result;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("merge failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

    public User findById(Integer id) {
        
        log.debug("getting User instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            User instance = entityManager.find(User.class, id);
            log.debug("get successful");
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserEntities**

```
package com.example.dbfirst.entities;
// Generated 25-Mar-2021, 4:12:53 pm by Hibernate Tools 5.2.12.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * User generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "mydb")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", length = 45)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", length = 45)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**User Pojo class**

```
 package com.example.dbfirst.pojo;
    // Generated 25-Mar-2021, 4:09:56 pm by Hibernate Tools 5.2.12.Final
    
    /**
     * User generated by hbm2java
     */
    public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    
        private Integer id;
        private String email;
        private String password;
    
        public User() {
        }
    
        public User(String email, String password) {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
        }
    
        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
    }
```

Now When I call **"users/id" from POSTMAN**, I am getting this error:

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Cannot invoke \"javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(java.lang.Class, Object)\" because \"this.entityManager\" is null",
 "path": "/users/2"
```

I might be missing some steps or I might have made some mistake somewhere.
It would be helpful if you can tell me the steps required to create spring boot project using database first approach (upto crud operation). You can also share some articles/link.
I have already looked at many articles to solve this issue. The reason I want database first approach are following:

1. I want to keep database part separate from spring project coding part (Don't want to mix them at such level)
2. I want to design database separately , completely independent of project type.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are mixing EJB and Spring. Is this a migration project?

Comment: Hi Simon, I am intending to learn spring boot. Most of the articles talked about creating database tables using entities defined in java classes. But I wanted to design database tables first, and then migrate them to spring project (similar to Asp.net database first approach). So I followed one article where JBoss was installed from eclipse marketplace to migrate db tables to spring project. I think EJB came along that. Correct me If I am wrong. I just need database first approach if it is possible with spring boot project.

Comment: Read this https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway

Answer (score 1):

In your case follow these steps:

1. Create your database table first.
2. Turn off auto-create and auto-update.
3. There is lot of unnecessary lines in your code.
4. Create only Entity class(add dto later)
5. Directly access repository from controller(remove service layer for now add later )
6. If have map columns to entity field properly other-wise it will cause errors(Use @Cloumn(name ="name")) for avoiding error and Use @Id for primary key.

You can refer:
[Disable auto update in spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652565/disable-auto-update-in-spring-data-jpa)

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/